# PHP image resizing unknow source size, known output size

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation, gd, image-scaling

I am working on a site at the moment, that requires the admins of the site to be able to upload pretty much any size of image, I then need to find a way to get the image down to the size required for the front end of the end the site, all this needs to be done without know what size of image the user is uploading, but the image always needs to scale to 209x293 without looking awful.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is impossible to scale ANY image to exact height and width and expect it not to look awful.  Consider an image with 10x10000 and you try to resize it to 203x293.

Comment: If you really want that specific exact size and you don't require the same proportions, than you want to CROP not SCALE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should argue with your client, to forget that rule(accept ANY image), and accept rather, only images in that proportion, **or better**, you can use a tool to crop the image, forcing the user to crop an image in your needed resolution.

[Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) is a library in Jquery which can help you a lot if you want to create that cropping feature.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your precise requirements, but since you tagged it with CodeIgniter, you can check out the [Image Manipulation Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html) which has everything you need to do the job.

Not knowing the size of images before uploading is, you know, quite a common problem...Just be careful of the MAX SIZE, which is set in your php.ini.

You might find useful also the page on [file uploading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) right in php's manual.

Comment: basically and an image can be uploaded straight form a digital camera, but the biggest it can displayed on the front end of the site will be 209x293, ideally an image will never be show on the site smaller or bigger than this.